# Cannot zoom out after zoom in too much when using ScaleGestureDetector

Tags: java, android

I used a custom view with a ScaleGestureDectector class. My problem is when I zoom in at 4.5x, my custom layout cannot be zoomed out.

Here is my code :

```
private class ScaleGestureListener
            extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float scaleFactor = mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor();

        mScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        setScaleX(getScaleX() * mScaleFactor);
        setScaleY(getScaleY() * mScaleFactor);

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Any solutions for this issue? I want to zoom in my layout at least 4.5x

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
float scaleFactor = mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor();
```

Do this:

```
float scaleFactor = Math.max(4.5F, mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor());
```

This ensures that your minimum zoom scale factor is 4.5

**EDIT:** I misunderstood your question. It appears as though you shouldn't be keeping track of mScaleFactor. The APIs do the heavy lifting for you.
According to the API, [`getScaleFactor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html#getScaleFactor())
returns `the scaling factor from the previous scale event to the current event.`

So when you keep track of mScaleFactor in a field, here's what goes wrong:

```
// With these two lines, you're multiplying the variable mScaleFactor.
// Suppose that it was 3, and we're zooming out by 0.66666666
// Now, mScaleFactor is 2.
float scaleFactor = mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor();
mScaleFactor = scaleFactor;

// Here, you're multiplying scaleX and scaleY by mScaleFactor (by 2. This effectively zooms in)
// You should only be multiplying them by 0.666666666 (effectively zooming out).
setScaleX(getScaleX() * mScaleFactor);
setScaleY(getScaleY() * mScaleFactor);

invalidate();
return true;
```

So your body should simply be this:

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

    setScaleX(getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
    setScaleY(getScaleY() * scaleFactor);

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when i zoom in at 3.5x, it is very difficult to zoom out